# RethinkDb OrderBy Before Filter, Performance

Tags: rethinkdb, rethinkdb-javascript

The data table is the biggest table in my db. I would like to query the db and then order it by the entries timestamps. Common sense would be to filter first and then manipulate the data.

```
queryA = r.table('data').filter(filter).filter(r.row('timestamp').minutes().lt(5)).orderBy('timestamp')
```

But this is not possible, because the filter creates a side table. And the command would throw an error (https://github.com/rethinkdb/rethinkdb/issues/4656).

So I was wondering if I put the `orderBy` first if this would crash the perfomance when the datatbse gets huge over time.

```
queryB = r.table('data').orderBy('timestamp').filter(filter).filter(r.row('timestamp').minutes().lt(5))
```

Currently I order it after querying, but usually datatbases are quicker in these processes.

```
queryA.run (err, entries)->
  ...
  entries = _.sortBy(entries, 'timestamp').reverse() #this process takes on my local machine ~2000ms
```

### Question:

What is the best approach (performance wise) to query this entries ordered by `timestamp`.

Edit:
The db is run with one shard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using an index is often the best way to improve performance.

For example, an index on the `timestamp` field can be created:

```
r.table('data').indexCreate('timestamp')
```

It can be used to sort documents:

```
r.table('data').orderBy({index: 'timestamp'})
```

Or to select a given range, for example the past hour:

```
r.table('data').between(r.now().sub(60*60), r.now(), {index: 'timestamp'})
```

The last two operations can be combined int one:

```
r.table('data').between(r.now().sub(60*60), r.maxval, {index: 'timestamp'}).orderBy({index: 'timestamp'})
```

Additional filters can also be added. A `filter` should always be placed after an indexed operation:

```
r.table('data').orderBy({index: 'timestamp'}).filter({colour: 'red'})
```

This restriction on filters is only for indexed operations. A regular `orderBy` can be placed after a filter:

```
r.table('data').filter({colour: 'red'}).orderBy('timestamp')
```

For more information, see the RethinkDB documentation: https://www.rethinkdb.com/docs/secondary-indexes/python/